# Weird css behaviour for ui-widget :active on iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, video-embedding

Scenario:

- Standard recommended iframes for embedding [Vimeo](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding) and [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Embedding_a_Player)
- Someone discovered that nothing happens on click/touch on iPhone
- Disabled css and js, everything works
- After some digging found that if disabling css `.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }` everything works as expected.

No jquery-ui js on these pages so no elements with .ui-* at all.
How can removing a line of css that shouldn't even be parsed cause this behaviour?

Comment: wtf is right. Wtf is your question?

Comment: Sorry. Edited question for clarity.

Comment: This question can't be answered as it's explained, because we don't know all of the details. Have you tried using developer tools to see if that .ui-widget :active class is getting applied? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3VxZQ/)

Comment: I don't have access to an XCode environment right now so can't debug at iphone level. The only thing I know is that mentioned selector somehow disables touch functionality for certain elements. My hope was that someone maybe knew if this was a known behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

This exact scenario is happening to me also.
Embed a youtube video using an iframe.
Example:

```
<iframe class="media-youtube-player" width="510" height="290" src="{$url to youtube}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In safari on ipad, tapping the video nothing happens.
I also bisected through my code and found that removing this line from 
the `jquery.ui.theme.css`:

```
.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }
```

fixed the problem.

I also tried modifying the line to:

```
.ui-widget :active {  }
```

This also causes the issue. Meaning the selector itself breaks the video in the ipad.

I also tried replacing the `.ui-widget :active` selector with just `:active`, this also 
causes the video to not play.

So, that's the fix... Delete that selector!

And outlines that appear on active elements inside `.ui-widget` you'll need to target more specifically.